# How to transform this script into $(document).ready construction?

Tags: jquery

I have some problem with syntax :(
Where and how need to close ready? This script must load only after loading the page.

```
function wr_hours(item){
//timeout
var sek = item.data("timeout");
var min = Math.floor((sek /60)%60) ;//sec
var hour = Math.floor((sek / (60*60)) %24) ;//hr
var days = Math.floor(sek /(24*60*60)) ;//days
var counterWrapper = $("#b-countdown");

if ( min < 10 ){
    min = "0" + min;
}
//CSS       
if ( hour != counterWrapper.data("left") ){
    var hourClass = hour == 0 ? 1 : hour;
    counterWrapper.attr("class", "left-" + hourClass).attr("data-left", hourClass)
}

var time_wr = hour + ":" + min;
item.html(time_wr);
item.data("timeout", (sek - 1) > 0 ? sek - 1 : 24 * 60 * 60);
}
setInterval(function(){
    $(".deadline").each(function(){ wr_hours($(this));})
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Wrap only the setInterval part inside the doc.ready as Matt said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery ready function can be used like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/* ADD YOUR CODE HERE */
});
```

In your example:

```
function wr_hours(item){
    //timeout
    var sek = item.data("timeout");
    var min = Math.floor((sek /60)%60) ;//sec
    var hour = Math.floor((sek / (60*60)) %24) ;//hr
    var days = Math.floor(sek /(24*60*60)) ;//days
    var counterWrapper = $("#b-countdown");

    if ( min < 10 ){
        min = "0" + min;
    }
    //CSS       
    if ( hour != counterWrapper.data("left") ){
        var hourClass = hour == 0 ? 1 : hour;
        counterWrapper.attr("class", "left-" + hourClass).attr("data-left", hourClass)
    }

    var time_wr = hour + ":" + min;
    item.html(time_wr);
    item.data("timeout", (sek - 1) > 0 ? sek - 1 : 24 * 60 * 60);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".deadline").each(function(){ wr_hours($(this));})
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function wr_hours(item){
        //timeout
        var sek = item.data("timeout");
        var min = Math.floor((sek /60)%60) ;//sec
        var hour = Math.floor((sek / (60*60)) %24) ;//hr
        var days = Math.floor(sek /(24*60*60)) ;//days
        var counterWrapper = $("#b-countdown");

        if ( min < 10 ){
            min = "0" + min;
        }
        //CSS       
        if ( hour != counterWrapper.data("left") ){
            var hourClass = hour == 0 ? 1 : hour;
            counterWrapper.attr("class", "left-" + hourClass).attr("data-left", hourClass)
        }

        var time_wr = hour + ":" + min;
        item.html(time_wr);
        item.data("timeout", (sek - 1) > 0 ? sek - 1 : 24 * 60 * 60);
    } setInterval(function(){
        $(".deadline").each(function(){ wr_hours($(this));})
    }, 1000);
});
```

But, since you are calling the function `wr_hours` in the `setInterval` function, another way is to just put the `setInterval` part within the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`